# How to add types information to JSON on serialization?

Tags: angularjs, json, datetime, json.net, iso8601

Angular requires `Date` objects in many places whereas JSON contains string representation of the date.

I want to add an array of properties which contain date values:

```
class Foo
{
    public int IntProp {get;set;}
    public DateTime? Prop1 {get;set;}
    public DateTime  Prop2 {get;set;}
    public Bar Bar {set;set;}
}

class Bar
{
    public DateTime Prop {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<DateTime?> Dates {get;set;} 
}
```

Foo should then be serialized like this:

```
{
   "IntProp": 1,
   "Prop1": "...",
   "Prop2": "...",
   "Bar": {
       "Prop": "..."
   },

   "<Dates>": [ "Prop1", "Prop2", "Bar.Prop", "Bar.Dates"]
}
```

This allows me to automatically convert strings to date objects at the client side without testing every property whether it is convertible to `Date` like it is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22435212/921054).

I can collect the paths of date properties, but have no idea how to add populated array to the root.

Comment: Maybe a bit of [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.  Json.NET can emit dates in many formats, see [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm).  How would you like the JSON for a `DateTIme` property to look without needing the additional `"<Dates>"` property?

Comment: @dbc I prefer it to be `Date`.  But I don't want to depart from ISO 8601. There is no special dedicated format for `Date`. We can distinguish strings, numbers, arrays, and objects, but dates are formatted as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to an intermediate [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and add the property there.  For instance, given the following converter:

```
public class PathLoggingDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public const string DatePathPropertyName = "<Dates>";

    readonly List<string> paths = new List<string>();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!base.CanConvert(objectType))
            return false;
        // Not for DateTimeOffset
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        if (value != null)
            paths.Add(writer.Path);
    }

    public IList<string> Paths { get { return paths; } }
}
```

You can do:

```
        var root = new Foo
        {
            IntProp = 101,
            Prop1 = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime(),
            Prop2 = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime(),
            Bar = new Bar
            {
                Prop = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime(),
                Dates = new List<DateTime?> { null, DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime() },
            },
        };

        var converter = new PathLoggingDateTimeConverter();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { converter } };
        var obj = JObject.FromObject(root, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
        obj[PathLoggingDateTimeConverter.DatePathPropertyName] = JToken.FromObject(converter.Paths);

        Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "IntProp": 101,
  "Prop1": "2016-10-25T04:00:00Z",
  "Prop2": "2016-10-25T04:00:00Z",
  "Bar": {
    "Prop": "2016-10-25T04:00:00Z",
    "Dates": [
      null,
      "2016-10-25T04:00:00Z"
    ]
  },
  "<Dates>": [
    "Prop1",
    "Prop2",
    "Bar.Prop",
    "Bar.Dates[1]"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's probably what I really need. Will try it tomorrow. Thanks.