# unable to get date format from json in my datatable

Tags: jquery, html, json

My table displays the date in this format `/Date(716841000000)/`. I am storing date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format using SQL Server 2008. How can I get date in a proper format using `JSON`? This is my mapping function. I am unable to get the required date format

```js
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var objdata = (response.d);
    var pm = JSON.parse(objdata);
    var len = objdata.length;
    arr = $.map(pm, function(n, i) {
      var arr_temp = {
        0: n.Id,
        1: n.name,
        2: n.gender,
        3: n.pincode,
        4: n.City,
        5: n.DOB,
        6: n.Id
      }
      arrtest[i] = n.Id;
      return arr_temp;
    });
```

[image: dob column is not in proper format]

Comment: How you are returning it from `server`? Could you show us server side code? or you could also try `5: new Date(n.DOB),` in your `js`.

Comment: For your ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435212/angular-js-format-date-from-json-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js format date from json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435212/angular-js-format-date-from-json-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(x.substr(6)));
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ag77zge/)

`substr` removes the /Date( part and `parseInt` ignores it at the end, passing the final result into the `Date` constructor.

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
  var objdata = (response.d);
  var pm = JSON.parse(objdata);
  var len = objdata.length;
  arr = $.map(pm, function(n, i) {
    var arr_temp = {
      0: n.Id,
      1: n.name,
      2: n.gender,
      3: n.pincode,
      4: n.City,
      5: n.DOB = new Date(parseInt(n.DOB.substr(6))),
      6: n.Id
    }
    arrtest[i] = n.Id;
    return arr_temp;
  });
}
```